# Shimano 105 front derailleur cage won't move at all

Tags: derailleur

Got a brand new shimano 105 FD double. I put the chain on the small ring and when I adjust the limit screw the cage can't go towards the frame enough so that the chain can't go to the largest rear cog because of the cage stop it from moving further to the frame. Then I started inspecting the FD and found the cage won't move a bit at all. To prove it I removed the two limit screws and tried to move the cage by hand and it just won't move. I don't have experience in it but watched many videos on YouTube and saw people moving the cage easily by hand to adjust FD. So wondering if there is something wrong with my FD?

Update:
The FD is fine, the problem is my FD hanger is extending a little bit too much from the seat post which makes the FD too far away from the frame. And my chain and cassette is 9 speed, and the FD is 10 speed so the FD cage a little bit tight here for a 9 speed chain. I googled a lot and found a solution is to use a 8 speed FD, which got much bigger size cage and can move further to the frame somehow. This plus a one mm BB spacer on the drive side solve the problem. I was not sure where was the problem at first so thought it might be the problem of FD itself, but it's just not compatible.

Comment: The springs are quite stiff.  If you have the derailer loose in your hands it takes a fair amount of finger force against the lever where the cable attaches to make it move.

Comment: Theres a mix of RD and FD in this question. You should be able to get the RD to shift into any cog in the rear independent of the FD. and you wont be able to move a working FD with your fingers easily.

Comment: @Batman sorry it's a FD, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Myabe have a very careful look at your cable route.

[image]

That little pin can make the pull action go around the pivot on the wrong side, actuating the mech against the stop.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see your point, but it's not the problem I got. Updated my post with the solution.